# MySQL query not returning the relevant data despite the data existing

Tags: mysql, xampp

This is my database

[image]

when I run the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE 'username'= 'abc' && 'password' = 'abc'
```

I am getting :

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

However username `abc` and password `abc` ***is present*** in my database . Why is MySQL returning zero rows?

Comment: `'username'` is literal. You're comparing one string against another. Use backticks around username and password instead.

Comment: Because you have syntax errors in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have add `"` to your column name

```
'username'= 'abc' && 'password' = 'abc'
```

If you execute below sql,you will find the select result is 0

```
SELECT 'username'= 'abc' && 'password' = 'abc';

+-----------------------------------------+
| 'username'= 'abc' && 'password' = 'abc' |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       0 |
+-----------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So your current sql is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 0;
```

that's the reason that your sql will return 0 results;

---

To make it work,you need to change `"` to `

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= 'abc' AND `password` = 'abc'
```

or just remove `"` in the column name

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username= 'abc' AND password = 'abc'
```